# How to access log messages for each celery task

Tags: python, logging, celery

I'm interested in accessing all log messages recorded during the life of an executed Celery task.

From the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html), I can create a logger for all tasks such that the task's id is automatically reported as part of the log:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Adding %s + %s', x, y)
    return x + y
```

Which produces a log message like this:

```
[2013-08-09 10:05:02,381: INFO/MainProcess] project.tasks.add[e56cd982-4c20-2328-af55-9cf4d63623df]: Adding 2 + 2
```

---

I *could* extract relevant messages from `logger` based on the reported task id, but that seems wonderfully inefficient and inelegant.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to see log messages before `task.ready()` returns `True` (much like `task.state` will give `PENDING` before completion).

I've read up on the [Celery logging improvements to 3.0](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.0.html#logging-improvements), the [Celery logging documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html), and the [`utils.log` source code](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/utils/log.html), but can't seem to find anything that suits my needs. Is it even possible to access the log messages of a pending task? I can easily return a `StringIO` instance catching messages along with my task's normal return value, but I'm interested in accessing the task's log *before* completion.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `logging.Filter` to your handlers which returns `True` (so the logging events are processed normally). The filter will see all events passed to the handler (unless filtered out by the handler's level) in the form of a `LogRecord` instance.